# Create VPC in GCP via CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, gcloud, vpc

Is there a way I can script an existing VPC and related subnets in GCP? I would like to script this out so that I can use gcloud CLI to recreate it.

I notice for some of the resources in GCP, there is a button at the bottom that outputs the equivalent REST API call. How do I use this to from the Gcloud CLI to recreate an existing VPC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be very useful across the board but, to my knowledge, it's not possible to invert `gcloud` commands to recreate the command that created existing resources.

You can determine the state of any GCP resource using the APIs and `GET`ting resources but you'd need then to reframe these as `gcloud` commands.

The equivalent REST and Cloud SDK commands presented in Console are very useful but these show you the `gcloud` and API equivalents of Console behaviors; usually create commands.

I recall reading something recently with Terraform where it is able to recreate configs from deployed resources but I've not seen this done for `gcloud`

Comment: Thank you. I am willing to explore Terraform / Pulumi as a way to recreate my entire GCP infrastructure automatically.

Comment: FYI in the end i just went with gcloud and kubectl commands to recreate my entire deployment (VPC, cluster, workloads, services, ingress etc). I can get my entire infrastructure up in less than 10minutes with this approach. :) :) That at least gets me to a point where i understand what needs to be done using native tools before i plunge into pulumi / terraform. it will make the transition much easier.